# Setting variables in while loops (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

This code capitalizes the first letter of each word in a string. 
Eg "this is a sentence" becomes "This Is A Sentence".

```
    def capitalize_words(string)
      words = string.split(" ")

      idx = 0
      while idx < words.length
        word = words[idx]

        word[0] = word[0].upcase
        words[idx] = word #this line of code can be made redundant, but why?           

        idx += 1
      end

      return words.join(" ")
    end
```

In the while statement, I don't understand why the third line is unnecessary. The second line sets the first letter of a word to capital:

```
  word[0] = word[0].upcase
```

how does the while statement know to refer back to the previous line

```
  word = words[idx]
```

to put the new capitalised-letter word back into the words array? I thought that when codes are executed, it always works in a forward fashion, please let me know if this understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `word` variable holds reference for object - the same object that is in `words` array. So if you modify this object, the object in array is modified also, because it's the same. 
BTW what you're trying to do here can be done much easier:

```
string.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

As Stefan suggested: Keep in mind that `capitalize` not only converts first character to uppercase, but also converts all remaining chars to lowercase. If this is not what you want, you can also do:

```
string.split(' ').map { |word| word.slice(0, 1).upcase + word.slice(1..-1) }
```

or use Stefan's solution with regexp:

```
string.gsub(/\b\w/) { |ch| ch.upcase }
```

Keep in mind that `\b` in regexp will 'split' your word not only by spaces, but by any word boudary.

Comment: You could even use a regex and avoid the array: `str.gsub(/\b\w/) { |ch| ch.upcase }`

Comment: BTW, `capitalize` converts the remaining characters to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using ruby then use answer as per @Marek's answer :

```
string.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

and If you are using `Ruby with Rails` then use this:

```
"this is a sentence".titleize
```

Comment: Please avoid pasting screens with console output - instead, put actual text here.

Comment: There is only a Ruby tag and Ruby doesn't provide `titleize`, so you need to qualify your answer.  Also, by providing only a picture of your code, readers cannot grab it for testing.

Comment: Note that `titleize` does *much* more: it applies inflection rules, replaces `_` and `-` with spaces, removes `_id` suffixes, converts `::` to `/` and splits camel-cased words.